# Android image background height

Tags: android

I write this code:

```
android:background="@drawable/back"
```

this code load the image and set the full screen mode
but i want set to the 70% of screen height
How can i do this?

Comment: use android:weightSum

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int width = 0, height = 0;

/* GET WIDTH AND HEIGHT OF SCREEN */
if (width == 0 && height == 0) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;
    } else {
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        width = d.getWidth();
        height = d.getHeight();
    }
}
```

here u can get device height and width set 70% like this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mPar = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (height*0.70));
```

Comment: How you can tell this is 70% of View. @Priyanka

Answer (score 0):

My This is helpful to you:

Make  `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="0.70"` of ImageView, other Invisible View for 30%.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutexample"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```